# Im going to be building 20x20 carport off of my Garage and wondering how far i have to dig for the 4x4 posts and will fill with concrete?

Tags: code-compliance, structural

For building off of my garage I'm going to build a 20x20 carport for winter. I will enclose building the walls during winter. My questions are is how far down do I gave to dig for the 4x4 posts, how far the slant I should use, and are they any codes I should be aware of? Otherwise I have have some knowledge of building random projects but just wanted a little insight and so I don't do enough or go overboard on the building.

Comment: Usually you check with local building department to find local frost level, and the posts/footings go below that.  Most codes for set backs(from other property lines) are local.  I imagine you mean roof slant, most times it comes down to what looks good beside your house.

Comment: You may also need a permit and/or zoning review, depending on the local area having jurisdiction.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general answer for this question.  You need to install the 4x4's in such a way that they are able to support the weight of the structure and remain stable through freeze/thaw cycles in your area.

Your local AHJ will certainly have their own standards based on their application of building codes and the local conditions.  They may have some guidelines that you can use to design the structure and draw up the plans you will need.

If not, you'll want to consult a local architect or licensed engineer to help you get the right structure.